# Remove everything to the right after a list of strings

Tags: arrays, vba, for-loop

I'm trying to remove everything to the right after a list of specific strings for a column.

```
Sub KeepItem()

Dim itemDescr As Range
Dim Rng As Range
Dim xChar As Variant

Set itemDescr = Range("$D:$D")
xChar = Array(" 1", " 2", " 3", " 4", " 5", " 6", " 7", " 8", " 9", " .")

For Each Rng In itemDescr
    xValue = Rng.Value
    Rng.Value = Left(xValue, InStr(xValue, xChar) - 1)
Next

End Sub
```

This

```
VITA COCO TROP 16.9OZ
ARGO CAROLINA HNY 13.5OZ GLS
ARGO GRN TEA GNGR 13.5OZ GLS
ARGO HIBISC SNGRIA 13.5OZ GLS
ARGO MOJI TEA 13.5OZ GLS
```

Should look like:

```
VITA COCO TROP
ARGO CAROLINA HNY
ARGO GRN TEA GNGR
ARGO HIBISC SNGRIA
ARGO MOJI TEA
```

I'm a novice VBA programmer and I'd appreciate your feedback.

Error in: (Type mismatch):

```
Rng.Value = Left(xValue, InStr(xValue, xChar) - 1)
```

Comment: do you want to remove anything after and including the first occurance of a number?

Comment: Is there an error with your current code?  Do you have a specific question related to your current code?

Comment: @Krishna I want to remove everything after and the first occurrence of a space followed by a number or decimal point

Comment: ok, updated the regexp below. this worked for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Will this work for you  if you want get text before a number occurance?

you need to add reference to Microsoft VBScript Reglar Expressions 5.5

```
Debug.print GetLeftPart ("TA COCO TROP 16.9OZ")

Function GetLeftPart (stringToCheck As String) as string
   Dim regex As New RegExp
   Dim regmatch As MatchCollection
   regex.Pattern = "\s\d"
   Set regmatch = regex.Execute(stringToCheck)
   GetLeftPart = Left(stringToCheck , regmatch.Item(0).FirstIndex)
End function
```

alternative more cumbersome way but since the author already started working along, this may suit the context

```
Sub KeepItem()

Dim itemDescr As Range
Dim Rng As Range
Dim xChar As Variant
Dim ele As Variant
Dim iFoundAt As Integer
Dim xValue As String

Set itemDescr = Range("$D:$D")
xChar = Array(" 1", " 2", " 3", " 4", " 5", " 6", " 7", " 8", " 9", " .")

For Each Rng In itemDescr
    iFoundAt = 0
    xValue = Rng.Value
    'find if this is a line we are interested in
    If xValue = "" Then GoTo continue 'Question - do you want to continue or stop. if stop replace continue with exit for
    For Each ele In xChar
        iFoundAt = InStr(xValue, ele)
        If iFoundAt > 0 Then Exit For
    Next
    If iFoundAt > 0 Then Rng.Value = Left(xValue, iFoundAt - 1)
continue:

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm unsure how to get this to work. Where am I plugging this in at? Is there anyway to tweak the code I provided?

Comment: the problem with the code you supplied is for every string, you will need to check for an occurrence of an item within the array. this is going to be cumbersome and less effective. but if that is the only way to go, then please see my edit. I strongly feel that you should change yours to the Regex way

Comment: were you able to fix it?

Comment: Yes, it works. Thanks for explaining it through. I still don't understand your Regex way, but I'm just a VBA beginner!

Answer (score 1):

Try this, for each cell in the range it loops 0 through 9 using a Split command to split the string into an array, we want everything to the left so we take the first element (index 0), then trim out the space.

```
Sub RemoveNumOnwards()
Dim X As Long, Y As Long
For X = 1 To Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For Y = 0 To 9
        Range("D" & X).Formula = Trim(Split(Range("D" & X).text, Y)(0))
    Next
Next
End Sub
```

Edit: Just saw your note about the decimal point, here is the updated code:

```
Sub RemoveNumOnwards()
Dim X As Long, Y As Long, xChar As Variant
xChar = Array(" 1", " 2", " 3", " 4", " 5", " 6", " 7", " 8", " 9", " .")
For X = 1 To Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For Y = LBound(xChar) To UBound(xChar)
        Range("D" & X).Formula = Trim(Split(Range("D" & X).text, xChar(Y))(0))
    Next
Next
End Sub
```